# Show a table with specific array content in angular

Tags: html, arrays, angular

In my app.component.ts i created the array "data", which consists of a few strings separated by comma.

I parse it into json and with console.log i am able tto clearly present it the way i'd like to doing this:

```
const jsonData = Papa.parse(content, {skipEmptyLines: true,});
jsonData.data.forEach(function(data){
    console.log(data[0], "|" , data[1] , "|" , data[2] , "|" , data[3]);
}
```

Its basically going through each line and then selecting the three data contents i'd like to be shown.

I want to display the array that way on my website in my app.component.html, but only the first three entries, because it has countless ones...

I've tried using the data as a json element

```
 <td>{{data.entry1}}</td>
```

But i didn't succeed. Its quite a simple task but im really stuck here. Could anyone explain why I dont get it?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to create an array that holds the data you would like to show.

**ts**

```
partialData = [];

yourFunction = () => {
    :
  jsonData.data.forEach(function(column) {
    const line = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      line.push(column[i]);
    };
    partialData.push(line);
  });
}
```

**html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let line of partialData">
  <td *ngFor="let column of line">
    {{column}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: But then it shows all the data right? I want to show only part of it. I've updated th question.

Comment: with "i++" i get Cannot assign to 'i' because it is a constant

Comment: Sorry it should be `let`. I have updated my answer again.

Comment: the array partialData gets empty and there is no output on the site